# What could cause 300+ connections from a simple query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am retrieving results from a table in MySQL 5.5. When I run even a basic query on this table hundreds of connections are shown in the Server Status screen in MySQL Workbench. Even for a simple query like:

```
SELECT 
  id
FROM 
  db.table;
```

I get 200 - 300+ connections shown in the Server Status screen.

This is the only table I get this result with. If I query other tables in the same db no extra connections are created.

Any suggestions for what the cause might be or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you post your table (SHOW CREATE TABLE\G) with some/all of your data (use a file upload service) so that people can reproduce this for themselves?

Comment: I did a mysqldump of the table and all its table then imported it into a separate database. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem with the connections so it is not the table structure or the data. I'm assuming the issue must be with options for the database or schema. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: I don't know what screen you are looking at.  Can you post a dump of it?  There can be multiple "threads" or "processes" sitting idle at once.  There can be multiple entries in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, again most of them in "Sleep" state.